# Classifying multivariate time-series data from multiple sites

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification

I'm trying to build a binary classifier using time-series data and kinda stuck on whether I'm on the right path. This seems relatively straight-forward if you only have data from one site, however in my case, I have data from multiple sites. A minimum example of my data would look like this:

Site 1 | class 0/1
 - time step1 | feature 1 ... feature 12
 - time step2 | feature 1 ... feature 12
 - ...
 - time step12 | feature 1 ... feature 12
...
...
Site n | class 0/1
 - time step1 | feature 1 ... feature 12
 - time step2 | feature 1 ... feature 12
 - ...
 - time step12 | feature 1 ... feature 12

As you can see, it's a relatively short time series but more features could be added if needed. There's data from a lot of sites though (let's say >50000). Each site comes with a binary label (either 1 or 0). I want to build a classifier for this use case. I was initially thinking I'd extract features from the time series for each site and use that for classification but because the underlying data is time series data, I really want to capture that.

So I started looking at time-series classification but most of the examples I've seen are for a single site classification. This begs the question, does that mean I have to train a classifier for each site (in excess of 50000 classifiers)?

Thanks in advance!